# Automatic acquisition of POP3/IMAP/SMTP parameters for an email server

Tags: smtp, imap, pop3

I'm trying to find a way in order to retrieve POP3/IMAP/SMTP parameters for a specific e-mail server. What I would like to do is the following: given any e-mail address, such as xxxx@server.com/it/etc, retrieve the correct POP3/IMAP settings in order to retrieve e-mails from that account and SMTP settings in order to send e-mails from that account.

Practically, what I search is a way to retrieve the server parameters needed in order to send and receive emails, that is, I search the same function that some e-mail client normally do when you create a new account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: LOL, that is kind a funny. So you ask: please give me a universal tool that allows me to use any account anywhere not owned by me so that I am able to missuse it however I like. That certainly should be not a problem for you, right?

Comment: You misunderstood my question. What I search is not a way to illegally use any e-mail account, but a way to retrieve the server parameters needed in order to send emails. Practically, I search the same function that some e-mail client normally do when you create a new account...

Comment: Don't you think this shows that you should ahve added these details to the question? I suggest you edit the question now and do so.

Answer (score 1):

The auto-configuration mechanism of Mozilla Thunderbird is described on the following page:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration

It uses either a_central database_ (known as ISPDB) or site-local configuration information accessible via special URLs. For example the correct IMAP settings for email addresses with the domain *web.de* can be found under the following URL:

- https://autoconfig.thunderbird.net/v1.1/web.de

Comment: Thank you, in fact I was studying the source codes that user3286911 linked to me, and I was seeing what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird does this as well as anyone and its source is available, so just [download](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Getting_comm-central) the source or [look at it on the web](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Viewing_and_searching_Mozilla_source_code_online).