# PHP: Automatic configuration of email provider

Tags: php, smtp, imap, phpmailer, pop3

[Automatic acquisition of POP3/IMAP/SMTP parameters for an email server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643831/automatic-acquisition-of-pop3-imap-smtp-parameters-for-an-email-server/21686333#21686333) discusses Mozilla ISPDB as source for configuration parameters like host, port etc for email services.

Does anybody know of an (preferably composer-enabled) PHP component that exposes ISPDB or even implements the full Thunderbird autoconfiguration algorithm (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration)? Potentially with phpmailer integration?

If not I'll likely start one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a reasonable idea, and I don't know of any other projects that cover this. The Mozilla docs look good - I think some of this information can sometimes be found in [DNS SRV records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record).

You don't need much in the way of PHPMailer integration (I'm the maintainer of PHPMailer) - it might help you find out what `Host` and `SMTPSecure` properties should be, so it can be an independent class. Generally these properties are are only useful for inbound - you rarely need to do it other than when setting up an inbound account; when sending via a relay you will typically only ever use one set of info, and a `Host` is more likely to be found using MX records for direct delivery.

Comment: thanks for your response. I do have a prototype up and running that goes from email address and password to sending via PHPMailer->IsSMTP(). Its too hacky for broader usage I'll do something about that and release on github.